# Disabling auto download in Safari

Tags: macos, security, download, safari

It seems like it's simply just enough to visit a webpage and the site can automatically start a download on your computer, no prompts, no warnings. Is there any way to make it behave like all the other browsers where they ask you before downloading a file?

This seems like an exploit that sites could take advantage of, especially with the *Open "safe" files after downloading* setting.

Comment: Anyone know a way of doing via the CMD line?

Comment: @Marc There's no way to do this *at all*.

Comment: Settings > General > File download location > Ask before each download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed one of the most annoying and insecure features of Safari that has been [constantly criticized](http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/auto-run-auto-download/) over the years and yet the developers insist they know better than the hackers (who obviously enjoy the fact the developers think like that).

You cannot turn this behavior off under Safari in any way I know of. It's insane, to say the least. Good thing you know not to trust the *Open "safe" files after downloading* setting. That's been the source of many Safari exploits.

I could only say for you to move to another browser. That's the only language project managers seem to understand. But you may need Safari for other reasons. So I cannot say that to you. Only... that you must learn to live with this.

Comment: Thanks for the background information and the link to the informative article.